# How is a cell different from array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell

I was coding in Matlab and came across a problem statement that demanded use of cells in MATLAB. I just wanted to know how does it function and is it more like vectors which can store heterogeneous values?

Comment: I recommend you read the docs, they are highly detailed: [Cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) and [arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Cells](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) are more like pointers. They can store anything of any size. The practical difference is that they use curly brackets `{}` to access the content (which can be a matrix, a string or even a function handle) and normal/round brackets `()` to access an element (returning a cell).

```
% create empty cell array
C = cell(4,1);
% write 5x5 matrix to cell
C{1} = magic(5);
% write 1x4 array to cell
C{2} = rand(1,4);
% write string to cell
C{3} = "This is a string";
% write cell to cell: the curly brackets first build a cell, which is then assigned to the cell array
C(4) = { rand(2,1) };


%% read cell
% get content
C{1} % this returns a matrix
% get element
C(1) % this returns a cell
```

Of course you cannot apply matrix operations to cells, e.g. `sum`, `+` or others...